# Members Can't Log-In to renew membership

Tags: civimember

Some of my members are having trouble renewing their membership. When they go to our renewal page, they enter their email and receive a message that says "The username or email you provided do not exist. Please try again." I can see that the email they are entering is the one we have on file in their contact file. What could the problem here be? Is there a setting we need to change in their contact files? This only happens with some members, some renew no problem.

Members enter their email and it should redirect them to a form to pay their fees (auto-filling information from the previous year). For our members with the issue logging in, it doesn't seem to recognize their email at all.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a custom page? Are you able to edit your question with a screenshot of the page where they enter their email?

Comment: What content management system are you using (Drupal, Wordpress, etc)? Logging in is usually handled by that and not CiviCRM.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Nicole! Lots of folks are asking questions to get enough info to help you troubleshoot.  You may want to edit your question to include a link to the renewal page, which would answer all the questions asked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Drupal? By default Drupal does not allow login by email. But there is a [module for that](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_emailusername).

Comment: No, we are not using Drupal. Some members are able to log in. Thank you, though!